# loading user images works in simulator but not on the iphone xcode 6 Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

Im trying to load(and upload) images in my app(by picture path). 
This is working in my simulator. everything works there. only when im trying to do this on the iphone itself it won't work and i see just the empty UIImageviews.

The paths are loaded the same as in the simulator. And originate from:

```
  PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: nil)
            {
                imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in

                cell.setString(info["PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey"] as String,name:dataUTI as String)
             }
```

And the PHImageFileSandboxExtentionTokenKey is split into the data and the url when loading the image.
this results in the simulator as :

```
/Users/Twizzler/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E671415-8B83-44DA-870F-19BF2BC11F8F/data/Containers/Data/Application/8872109F-3784-40EB-BEB6-4E9FDABE013D/Documents/1613945_10200645161051698_4122753901212984922_n.jpg
```

and in the iphone as:

```
/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2607.JPG
```

Im loading the image like this:

```
  let image = UIImage(named: "/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2607.JPG")
        cell.imageView.image = image
```

in this case i put the image url hardcoded (this is in the final app an array of images)

I don't get an error or stack trace. When placeing a breakpoint im seeing the image information in the same way as the simulator

as suggested by the answer im now trying to load them as follows:

```
 let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2607.JPG")
        cell.imageView.image = image
```

This isn't working and i can't upload the files

Comment: Apps are sandboxed. On a real (non-jailbroken) device, an app has no direct access to any files outside of its sandbox.

Comment: The path `/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2607.JPG`is not accessible directly. It looks like an `ALAssets` URL. You should always copy and use image within your apps sandbox.

Comment: Okey and how do i get the image in my sandbox?(i know its a silly question. but i can only find the ones that use the way i have it now)

Comment: [Determining Where to Store Your App-Specific Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html)

Comment: The files im trying to use are NOT app specific

Answer (score 0):

That’s not how `imageNamed` works—as the documentation states, that looks for an image with the given name inside your app’s bundle. Try `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

Comment: It doesn't work still the same error. The problem is that i can't get the user taken pictures(camera roll) to show and can't upload them to a server

Answer (score 0):

Well i fixed it! after some puzzling days im now using this way to access upload and
`cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data:  array[indexPath.row][0] as NSData)`
This shows the image. I can save the NSData in the CoreData and reload the image on this way.

To lighten the load on the system im using this:

```
cellData.checked = 1
            var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cell.imageView.image, 1)
            self.array.append([imageData,cellData.imageData] )

            let myObj : ViewControllerImagePicker = self.parentViewController as ViewControllerImagePicker
            let textfield: UILabel = myObj.amountLabel! as UILabel
            textfield.text = String(self.array.count )
            cell.textLabel.alpha = 1
```

this code is being called when there is clicked on a cell. by setting the cellData.imageData i can recall the cells (when clicking back to the collection view)

I do not know if the way im doing it is correct or works with more that 10 files because of data usage problems. But in my case with a max of 6 selected pictures it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The simulator works completely different than a real device when it comes to files, the app bundle and sandboxing.

For starters the simulator will let you write to and add or change files in your app bundle. iOS running on a real device won't let you do this.

You can't hardcode any paths in your app.  Even if it works today or on your device in test mode that doesn't mean it will work on a released version.  And even if it does it could stop working on any update. Apple several times has changed where things are stored and the path structure in the phone. And where you are allowed to write.

Make bundle calls to get the path locations of standard folders.

Use the assets library to load images from the photo library, or to save them there.

There are tons of resources and tutorials online on how to do this.